# Why can't I create an Azure AD tenant?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I'm trying to get my app verified by microsoft. The first step is to become a microsoft partner but I can't figure out how to sign in?

[image]

When I try to create an Azure AD tenant I'm told I don't have permission (even though I own the account).

I can't sign in with the email address I use to log into Azure because that is a personal email and not a work email. It won't accept my personal email.

I'm sure there is just some big hole here in my understanding about the creation of an Azure AD tenant but I can't for the life of me figure out what that hole is.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Did you check by what name did you create the tenant while signing up for Azure initially? Because that's the exact UPN/domain suffix you will have to use while logging into Azure, i.e., <something@giventenantname.onmicrosoft.com> or if your tenant name is verified as the domain name in your tenant, then that should follow your username.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

•   While signing up for Azure, you might have entered a domain name or tenant name for your organization to be distinguished recognized. If this entered domain name is not verified in Azure AD, then while signing up, it will be followed by ‘onmicrosoft.com’.

•   Thus, while signing into azure, you should use that assigned or given domain name that was distinguished available and chosen by you to be used as your Azure’s default UPN suffix. As that user ID will be having global administrator privileges in your Azure tenant and the MPN account should be linked to that account only.

•   Please refer to the image below for hint on organization name selection during Azure AD signup and its availability: -

[image: Azure domain name availability]

Thus, once you have gone ahead after signing up through this page and confirmed the verification of mail ID and given phone number, your Azure login username would be ‘username@selecteddomainname.onmicrosoft.com’. Also, refer to the documentation link below for more details: -

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/fundamentals/add-custom-domain

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/fundamentals/active-directory-get-started-premium